# Animation won't restart after view change

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

First time the view loads the animation is applied but after that when ever the view is loaded - nothing happens.

Should be straightforward - but...

The code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{    
[self animateLabel];    
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[self.labelMarkTheSpot.layer removeAllAnimations];  
}

- (void)animateLabel{

UIViewAnimationOptions options = (UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState);

CGAffineTransform scaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:options animations:^{
    self.labelMarkTheSpot.transform = scaleFactor;        
}
completion:nil];
}
```

(starting the animation in viewWillAppear makes no difference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a line at the beginning of `animateLabel` to reset the view to its scale before the animation:

```
self.labelMarkTheSpot.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
```

What's happening is once it has animated to 1.1, 1.1; it stays that way, and the animation when the view re-appears doesn't do anything (1.1 to 1.1). By resetting it to 1.0 (or whatever you want it to initially be, as the starting point for the animation), it will always go from 1.0 to 1.1.

Comment: Unfortunately, it makes no difference.
With the current animation options, it should pick up where it left the last time, and animate over and over and...

Comment: At some point i had added 
[self.labelMarkTheSpot.layer removeAllAnimations]

Removing that and adding your suggestion works. Thank You